# How to output class definitions into unique text files?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a header file which contains several class declarations (all starting with BusType)...How can I parse and output each class into it's own text file?

```
class BusTypeA
{
    struct DummyA
    {
        //etc
    };
    //etc
};

class BusTypeB
{
    struct DummyB
    {
        //etc
    };
    //etc
};

class BusType1
{
    struct Dummy1
    {
        //etc
    };
    //etc
};

//many more classes...
```

Maybe do a first pass on the file gathering all BusTypes into variables and do something like this in a for loop?

```
sed -n '/class BusTypeA/,/class BusTypeB/ p' >> BusTypeA.txt
sed -n '/class BusTypeB/,/class BusType1/ p' >> BusTypeB.txt
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk '/^class/{f=$2;p=1} p&&/^};/{print>>f;p=0} p{print>>f}' file
```

As suggested in the comment by @hek2mgl,

```
awk '/^class/{f=$2;p=1} p&&/^};/{print>>f;close(f);p=0} p{print>>f;close(f);}'
```

Comment: Just a side note, I don't think it is a problem in this case: When you are writing to a dynamically generated filename like `f` in this case, awk will open a file descriptor but it won't close it until the end of the program. This can lead to the situation that you run out of file descriptors. To avoid that you need to explicitly call `close(f)`.

Comment: You probably mean `>`, not `>>`. Awk is not shell, the semantics of those operations are different. You shouldn't have a `close(f);` after the last `print` though, it should be right before `f=$2` or after the first print as you have it. You should also separate the `p` action from the `/^};/` action to avoid redundantly specifying `print` twice. eg. `awk '/^class/{f=$2;p=1} p{print>f} /^};/{close(f);p=0}'` and of course you don't actually need a separate flag variable named `p`, it can be just: `awk '/^class/{f=$2} f{print>f} /^};/{close(f);f=""}'`

Answer (score 3):

Try `csplit`:

```
csplit input.txt '/^class BusType.*/' {*}
```

It is **c**ontent **split** utility. You define regexp pattern, and number of split which should be made - `{*}` means unlimited

Comment: I wish there was a way to mark favorite answers so that next time I really need this `csplit` and can't remember its name I could look it up in favorites instead of a semantic orgy in Google.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print > $2".txt"}' file
```

depends on the empty line separating the class definitions.  Set `awk` to paragraph mode, print current record to the file named after second field (plus suffix).